# Internet Explorer 11 aborting mp4 requests

Tags: windows-7, registry, internet-explorer-11, trusted-sites

We have an online video library for corporate and institutional clients, and recently we obtained a client, using IE11 and Windows 7 with a corporate proxy, who are having trouble viewing videos. We know it's not a firewall issue because they can watch the first video on the page (each web page has multiple videos), but any subsequent request for the mp4 is aborted by IE11, and the request is never made. So far we have

- added the domain to trusted sites
- added the domain to the registry
- changing the endpoint and domain of the video requests

The users have no issue when testing in Chrome or IE11 on Windows 10 -- it seems to be strictly an issue with Windows 7.  We would like to provide guidance to this organization but we're really out of ideas.  Just wondering whether anyone else has had a similar issue, and can point me in the right direction.

**UPDATE**

We were able to get this to play by  removing the https value from the reigstry key for both the domain of the website and the domain of the video endpoint on HKEY_CURRENT_MACHINE ( Preferences > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Internet Settings > ZoneMap >Domains ).  My understanding is that this changes the site from 'Trusted Zone' to 'Internet Zone'. Unfortunately, while this worked in playing the videos, it actually blocked font files from being downloaded, and now our play/pause buttons (which use font glyphs) are missing.

Comment: Have you ever tried to use F12 developer tools to check the Network capture and check whether it contains some error?

Comment: Yes -- I actually updated this question with additional information

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following method to allow IE browser to download the font:

**Using Internet options**

Open the Internet Tools, and click the Internet Options, under the Security tab, select a zone to change security settings. Click the "Custom level…", in the popup modal, find the Fond download  option and select the Enable option.
Finally, click the OK button to apply the setting.

[image]

**Using Registry key settings.**

(1) Open Run window and type regedit to open registry editor.

(2) Navigate to location below.
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3

(3) Find the "1604" registry key.

(4) Double click on it and set its desired value. (To disable : 3, To enable : 0, To prompt : 1)

(5) Click on OK to close the dialog.

(6) Restart Internet Explorer to take effect of changes.